# Change file icon while vscode is installed?

Tags: windows-10, icons, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to change the icons of my code files (e.g. `.c`, `.cpp`, `.js`, `.lua`, etc.) and I've been having a super annoying problem:

Because I use VSCode, all the icons are grouped together (VSCode by default uses this one icon for all the files) and if I use the registry editor or any other programs, changing one changes *all* of them and I can't figure out how to separate them.

Any ideas?

Here is what my main folder looks like now. It's maddening:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article
[File and Folder Icons in VS Code!](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/09/08/icon-themes)
lists the icon themes in VScode.

The File Icon Theme can be changed from the *File > Preferences* menu or the
Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).
Perhaps the
[Seti Icon Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/09/08/icon-themes#_seti-icon-theme)
will be a better fit for you.

If the built-in icon themes are not enough, there also exist extensions such as the free
[vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)
or
[file-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=file-icons.file-icons).

---

For changing the icon used by a file extension in Windows Explorer,
you could use the free utility
[FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html),
which allows changing every aspect of a file-type.

If you would rather do it manually in the registry, see:

- [How to Assign a Custom Icon to a File Type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type)
- [How to Change the Icon for a File Type in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-default-icon-file-type-windows/)

Comment: Yes, but how do I make it work with file explorer? Still the default icon (or the one I changed it to)

Comment: I see that Explorer is the problem. I wonder if setting *Preferences: File Icon Theme* to `None` might help. Or perhaps `"explorer.decorations.badges": false`. But I added in my answer a part about changing Windows icon associations for a file-type.